# How to permit access to my config.yaml file? (Raspbian, Azure IoT Edge)

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, raspbian, azure-iot-edge

I've been going through the Azure IoT Edge documentation to connect a Raspberry Pi 4 using Raspbian Stretch to the Azure Cloud. The IoT Edge daemon is 'active (running)' but when I run 'iotedge check' I get the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$iotedge check --verbose
Configuration checks
--------------------
x config.yaml is well-formed - Error
   Could not open file /etc/iotedge/config.yaml. You might need to run this command as a root.
       caused by: Permission denied (os error 13)

0 check(s) succeeded.
1 check(s) raised errors.
```

I am fairly new to this so may have made an obvious error but can't find anything on google, Azure or Stack Overflow that applies. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to run the command with, as the command requires the priviledge to open the file:

```
sudo iotedge check
```

Comment: Ah I misunderstood what the error was, thanks for your help @kgalic!